# Understanding in excel vba when reaching the limit of an A4 sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have to write a procedure that will write multiple lines on a new sheet in Excel. My problem is that I have to interrupt the insertion of new lines when the sheet reaches the limit of an A4 sheet and reached this limit I will have to create a new sheet, insert in the head different data (not a page header) and then resume inserting lines.
I can not simply count the lines because the lines that I will insert will be of variable height. There will also be a fixed page footer.

So I ask myself: is there a property or something in excel vba that returns me the position Y of a cell on a sheet a4 (portrait)?
In this way I could understand in a loop when I have to change sheet

Comment: You could use worksheet("your sheet").HPageBreaks.location.row. The problem is that it only detects pagebreaks that already exists. So you would have to input your data into the sheet and then insert the header and footer afterwards.

Comment: When you do a print review, you can see some dashed lines at the margins of your printed sheet. Try to figure out how those lines get there.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting new rows with different heights, check their heights using

```
Rows(i).RowHeight
```

add this height in some variable like

```
total_height = total_height + Rows(i).RowHeight
```

Put a check at a certain total_height to break your loop to start new page. 
You have to decide this height yourself, as in excel A4 does not have constant height, it is dynamic based on the data and can be increased or decreased

You have to test the breaking height number based on your data that which height looks good to you.

Before continuing to the new page run this code on the finished page

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup

    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

End With
```